# Targetting Android Mobile Devices (Galaxy S) with CSS

Tags: android, css, resolution, dpi, targeting

I'm trying to target Android devices with a CSS file, but I've been unsuccessful until now.
I'm using the following CSS code:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 800px) {
    body { max-width: 100%; background-color:#000; }
}
```

I'm also invoking the css code with the following line in the PHP file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="small.css" />
```

Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Within PHP, you can check [user agent](http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/mobile_ids.html), and based on that apply an appropriate style sheet.

And don't forget the viewport setting within a meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
```